# Similar iOS apps from same developer

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I'm planning on developing multiple apps that will be similar in design but will target various geographical locations, all under the same developer license. I know Google will, but will Apple allow this?

Comment: Definitely allowed, but cross your fingers that you never want to implement push notifications. The resulting manual certificate management for that is epic (unless it's been improved in the last couple of years, and on this topic I'm therefore an old, out-of-touch man).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Comment: Please don't. This is why it is so hard to find a good app on the store. There are far too many apps. Make one app and use IAP to let the user purchase a geographical location.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple allows this. For example, Gett (GetTaxi) has different apps for US and other stores. They all feature the same UI/UX design, bar small differences.